# Why is it that when a user sends a message to my Telegram bot, other users are not able to use the bot?

Tags: c#, .net, telegram-bot

I wrote a Telegram bot with C# language and Telegram.bot package, which starts with the /start command and after touching each of the inline keyboards, a question related to the business bot is asked. The problem is that when one person puts /start in the bot, other people cannot use the bot.
What's wrong with bot?

```
 public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
        var myService = host.Services.GetRequiredService<Business>();
        await myService.MainMethod();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                services.AddScoped<Business>();
            });

}
```

and Business class:

```
 public async Task MainMethod()
    {
        var botClient = new TelegramBotClient("token");            
        using CancellationTokenSource cts = new();

        // StartReceiving does not block the caller thread. Receiving is done on the ThreadPool.
        ReceiverOptions receiverOptions = new()
        {
            AllowedUpdates = Array.Empty<UpdateType>() // receive all update types except ChatMember related updates
        };

        botClient.StartReceiving(
            updateHandler: HandleUpdateAsync,
        pollingErrorHandler: HandlePollingErrorAsync,
        receiverOptions: receiverOptions,
        cancellationToken: cts.Token
    );

        var me = await botClient.GetMeAsync();

        Console.WriteLine($"Start listening for @{me.Username}");
        Console.ReadLine();

        // Send cancellation request to stop bot
        cts.Cancel();

        
        async Task HandleUpdateAsync(ITelegramBotClient botClient, Update update, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            // Only process Message updates: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message
            if (update.Message is not { } message)
                return;
            // Only process text messages
            if (message.Text is not { } messageText)
                return;

            var chatId = message.Chat.Id;
            var name = message.Chat.FirstName;

            Console.WriteLine($"Received a '{messageText}' message in chat {chatId}.");

            // Echo received message text
            switch (message.Text)
            {
                case "/start":
                    await StartMessage(botClient, chatId, cancellationToken);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

            int offset = 0;
            try
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    Update[] arrayUpdate = botClient.GetUpdatesAsync(offset).Result;

                    foreach (var singleUpdate in arrayUpdate)
                    {
                        offset = singleUpdate.Id + 1;
                        update = singleUpdate;
                        if (singleUpdate.CallbackQuery != null)
                        {
                            switch (singleUpdate.CallbackQuery.Data)
                            {
                                case "/start":
                                    await HandleUpdateAsync(botClient, update, cancellationToken);
                                    break;
                                case "BuyService":
                                    await BuyService(botClient, update, chatId, cancellationToken);
                                    break;
etc..
}
```

I tried to solve this problem by using threads, but I did not succeed. Please help me. Thank you

Comment: Please paste your code as text instead of an image.

Comment: I replaced the codes with images

Comment: I think your `while (true)` loop never ends. Why do you need it if you have polling method

Comment: The problem is that when I remove this loop, the rest of the inline keyboards stop working. Am I using them in the right way and in the right place?